# How to write results to an output file

Tags: python, csv, file-io

I have a problem trying to output simple results to an output file. Here I tried to make some fake data using numpy but that is causing problems of its own, I keep getting all sorts of errors basically to do with the index not being suscriptable or invalid index to scalar variable.

What I want is an output csv file that reads like this:

```
LineID  ColA    ColB    ColC
1  8  2 93
2  7  3 86
3  7  3 89
4  9  2 90
```

Code used:

```
import csv
import numpy as np



z=np.array([[1,8,2,93],[2,7,3,86],[3,7,3,89],[4,9,2,90]])

#b=np.array(z)
b=z
print('\n','b is : ','\n', b, '\n')

nummy=z[:,0]
ColA_results = z[:,1]
ColB_results = z[:,2]
ColC_results = z[:,3]
print('nummy: ',nummy)
print('ColA_results: ',ColA_results)
print('ColB_results: ',ColB_results)
print('ColC_results: ',ColC_results)

results_filename = (r'/Users/imagexpertinc/Desktop/steve_results/demo_03.csv')
with open(results_filename, 'w', newline='') as filey: ## Python 3... with open('/pythonwork/thefile_subset11.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(filey, delimiter = '\t', lineterminator='\n')
    csv_writer.writerow(['LineID', 'ColA','ColB','ColC'])
filey.close()




size_of_z=len(z)

indy = range(size_of_z)
print('indy is: ',indy)


for i in indy:
    print('i is :',i)
    print('nummy[i] is: ',nummy[i])
    #nummy = nummy[i]
    ColA_results = ColA_results[i]
    ColB_results = ColB_results[i]
    ColC_results = ColC_results[i]

    with open(results_filename, 'a') as filey: ## Python 3... with open('/pythonwork/thefile_subset11.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(filey, delimiter = '\t', lineterminator='\n')
        csv_writer.writerow([nummy, ColA_results, ColB_results, ColC_results])
```

Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the output/error you are getting right now/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
import csv
import numpy as np

z=np.array([[1,8,2,93],[2,7,3,86],[3,7,3,89],[4,9,2,90]])

nummy=z[:,0]
ColA_results = z[:,1]
ColB_results = z[:,2]
ColC_results = z[:,3]

results_filename = (r'/Users/imagexpertinc/Desktop/steve_results/demo_03.csv')
with open(results_filename, 'w', newline='') as filey: ## Python 3... with open('/pythonwork/thefile_subset11.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(filey, delimiter = '\t', lineterminator='\n')
    csv_writer.writerow(['LineID', 'ColA','ColB','ColC'])

    for i in range(z.shape[0]):
        csv_writer.writerow([nummy[i], ColA_results[i], ColB_results[i], ColC_results[i]])
filey.close()
```

Comment: Hi abhilb, I see your solution works perfectly but could I ask what the range(z.shape[0]): line does?

Comment: z.shape returns a tuple. First element of that will be the number of rows and second the number of columns. So here z.shape[0] corresponds to the number of rows. range(z.shape[0]) will then give 0 till number of rows - 1

Answer (score 1):

You have overthought the problem. An numpy array is seen by Python as an iterable of iterables, and can be passed directly to `csv.writer.writerows` (notice the `s` in row**s**):

```
import csv
import numpy as np



z=np.array([[1,8,2,93],[2,7,3,86],[3,7,3,89],[4,9,2,90]])

results_filename = ('/Users/imagexpertinc/Desktop/steve_results/demo_03.csv')
with open(results_filename, 'w', newline='') as filey:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(filey, delimiter = '\t', lineterminator='\n')
    csv_writer.writerow(['LineID', 'ColA','ColB','ColC'])

    csv_writer.writerows(z)
```